# Symmetric and Asymmetric indistinguishabilty experiment

Tags: key-generation, indistinguishability

In each of those experiments, we have a function $Gen(x)$ who generates the key or a pair of keys respectively for symmetric or asymmetric algorithms. $x = 1^n$ : I read on other questions that is a $1$ string bit of length $n$, but I didnìt understood why it is used value as input to generate the key.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Consider a function that takes a parameter $n$ and outputs a uniformly random $n-bit$ key. Without the $n$ what do you expect the Key-Gen outputs? Consider AES, the Key-Gen should output 128,192,256, or 5? That is the formalization and that $n$ is considered the security parameter.

Comment: some dupes and/or enlightening Q/A: [What exactly is a “security parameter”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52309/18298). [What is the difference between security parameter and b-bit security?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/81593/18298) [Parameterizing adversaries with security parameters](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37231/18298). If still not clear, let us know.